# how to use a ruby rails variable in the curl (bash) script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, curl

I am trying to run this curl script in my ruby rails application:

```
%x{ curl -F token='08F14AE57696E458BA6FC6A203F57E69' -F overwriteBehavior=normal 
-F content=record -F type=flat -F format=json 
-F data='[{"record_id":"123","seat_id_seq":"bbb","address":"bbb","price":"bbb","email":"bbb","tickets1_complete":"2"}]'  
'https://cri-datacap.org/api/' }
```

and its working fine. Now I want don't want to hardcode the values so i am trying to give this values by the variable.

These variable contains value from the text field on my rails application:

```
%x{ curl -F token='08F14AE57696E458BA6FC6A203F57E69' -F overwriteBehavior=normal 
-F content=record -F type=flat -F format=json 
-F data='[{"record_id":"#{params[:record_id]}","seat_id_seq":"bbb","address":"bbb","price":"bbb","email":"bbb","tickets1_complete":"2"}]'  
'https://cri-datacap.org/api/' }
```

so I have tried for one variable record_id, but its not working.. This script is written in my controller.

Comment: Why not use an HTTP library instead of curl?

Comment: I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: Here are some simple examples to get you started; it's a Ruby std library. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact that using `curl` externally when libraries like [`curb`](https://github.com/taf2/curb) exist, using `%x{...}` for this is extremely messy. What you want to do is call `system`:

```
data = [
  {
    record_id: params[:record_id],
    seat_id_seq: "bbb",
    address: "bbb",
    price: "bbb",
    email: "bbb",
    tickets1_complete: 2
  }
]

system(
  "curl",
  "-F", "overwriteBehavior=normal",
  "-F", "content=record",
  "-F", "type=flat",
  "-F", "format=json",
  "-F", "data=#{JSON.dump(data)}",
  'https://cri-datacap.org/api/'
)
```

When you're writing JSON data, do try and use `JSON.dump` or `.to_json` to ensure your document is 100% valid.

Comment: I replaced payload with data, but it is still not inserting data .

Comment: It looks like , it is not getting data in params[:record_id]

Comment: I'd switch this over to `curb` code at the very least, if not [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) before attempting to get everything working properly. That can make debugging a lot less messy.

Comment: I actually do not know how to use curb.. I found this solution on net, and thought to try

Comment: That's why they have documentation, it helps you understand. `curb` isn't hard to use, it's essentially 1:1 mapped against `curl` command-line arguments, just in Ruby code.

Comment: ok..but do you have any idea why the values are not coming from text box to params[:record_id]

Comment: I don't, but I bet `log/development.log` does. Have a look in there to see if that's being populated correctly.

Comment: It is saying that **the data being imported is not formatted correctly**